# How to add new folder to the list of personal folders (Documents, Download, etc)

Tags: linux, desktop

I would like to add some very used folders to the list of personal/important folders in Files (or Dolphin, or Places) - (Documents, Downloads, NewFolder1, NewFolder2, etc). This folders are located in a local disk.
I remember I saw a post long time ago where I should update two files, one located in my .local folder and other somewhere else, but I do not remember what files should I update.
I am using OpenSuse Leap 15.4, Ubuntu 22.04 and Garuda.
Thank you.

Comment: In Ubuntu I mount my data partition where I have moved all folders in /home & added some more & then linked all those folders back into /home. I link same data folders into multiple copies of Ubuntu so my test installs work same as main working install. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: Thank you oldfred, but my intent is to add new folders to the 'default' list

Comment: If this is not a matter of only Files / Dolphin / Places then you might want to try Thunar I am using it and You can drag'n'drop folder directly to left sidebar and have shortcut there as long as you wish.

Comment: I am using Dolphin & right-click on places to add entry.